# Writing Apache Beam Tagged Output (Dataflow runner) to different BQ tables

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It seems that I get an issue writing tagged PCollections to multiple destination tables in BQ. The pipeline executes with no errors, but no data gets written.

If I execute the pipeline without `TaggedOutput`, PCollection elements are correctly generated and correctly written to the BQ table on its own (albeit a single table, instead of multiple). So I believe the issue is misunderstanding how `TaggedOutput` actually works?

---

**Code**

I have a process fn which generated tagged output:

```
class ProcessFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, el):
        if el > 5:
             yield TaggedOutput('more_than_5', el)
        else:
             yield TaggedOutput('less_than_5', el)
```

And the pipeline:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:

    # Read the table rows into a PCollection.
    results = (
        p
        | "read" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=args.input_table, use_standard_sql=True)
        | "process rows" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessFn()).with_outputs(
                                        'more_than_5',
                                        main='less_than_5')
    )

    results.less_than_5 | "write to bq 1" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.less_than_5',
            schema=less_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )


    results.more_than_5 | "write to bq 2" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.more_than_5',
            schema=more_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with_outputs(main=...)` keyword is used for yields without the `TaggedOutput`. In this case, you should probably be writing `with_outputs('more_than_5', 'less_than_5')`.  Either accessing the result by name or unpacking as a tuple should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the way getting result with multi sinks in your code.

The result should be retrieved as a Tuple :

```py
results_less_than_5, result_more_than_5 = (
        p
        | "read" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=args.input_table, use_standard_sql=True)
        | "process rows" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessFn()).with_outputs(
                                        'more_than_5',
                                        main='less_than_5')
    )

results_less_than_5 | "write to bq 1" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.less_than_5',
            schema=less_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )


result_more_than_5 | "write to bq 2" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.more_than_5',
            schema=more_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )
```

Can you try with this syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Because [with_outputs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.ParDo.with_outputs) returns a `DoOutputsTuple object`, Tags specified in `with_outputs` are attributes on the returned `DoOutputsTuple` object. The tags give access to the corresponding output PCollections.

So you can access your tags like `results.some_tag` and you can omit the parameters for `with_outputs` like examples in [this document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/).

So with your current `ProcessFn` you can modify the pipeline like this:

```
results = (
        p
        | "read" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=args.input_table, use_standard_sql=True)
        | "process rows" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessFn()).with_outputs() # << omit the parameters here
    )

results.less_than_5 | "write to bq 1" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.less_than_5',
            schema=less_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )


result.more_than_5 | "write to bq 2" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            'dataset.more_than_5',
            schema=more_than_5_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    )
```